# Python Regular Expression: re.findall doesn`t see all mathces

Tags: python, regex

I would like to find all mathces by such pattern: **(one letter)(three figures)(two letter)(two or three figures)**.

So my python regular expression is:

```
[А,В,Е,К,М,Н,О,Р,С,Т,У,Х]\d{3}[А,В,Е,К,М,Н,О,Р,С,Т,У,Х]{2}\d{2,3}
```

where

- `[А,В,Е,К,М,Н,О,Р,С,Т,У,Х]` is letters` set;
- `\d{num}` is for any figure repeated num times.

I wrote this code to solve my problem:

```
import re
pattern = r"[А,В,Е,К,М,Н,О,Р,С,Т,У,Х]\d{3}[А,В,Е,К,М,Н,О,Р,С,Т,У,Х]{2}\d{2,3}"
string = "A123AA11 А222АА123 A12AA123 A123CC1234 AA123A12"
re.findall(pattern, string)
```

I suspect to see this list of strings: `['A123AA11', 'А222АА123']`

But I got this one: `['А222АА123']`

What is the problem? Where did I make a mistake?

Comment: I don't where you get your A, but it seems that is it not the classic A, your A are different, I don't know why

Comment: You have a Cyrillic `А` in the regex, and the first `A123AA11` contains Latin `A` char. So, what are you after?

Comment: @azro Well spotted: that is a Cyrillic A: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_(Cyrillic) .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how, but the `A` in your regex is [A_(Cyrillic)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_(Cyrillic)) (the `U+0410` or (`1040d`) one from [ASCII](https://asecuritysite.com/coding/asc2?val=1024%2C1280))

```
print(ord("А"))  # 1040
print(ord("A"))  # 65
```

---

Then the square bracket notation means an OR between every values so here `[А,В,Е,К,М,Н,О,Р,С,Т,У,Х]` is same as `[ABEKMHOPCTYX,]` **comma included**, you only need `[ABEKMHOPCTYX]`

Giving

```
string = "A123AA11 A222AA123 A12AA123 A123CC1234 A123A12"
pattern = r"[ABEKMHOPCTYX]\d{3}[ABEKMHOPCTYX]{2}\d{2,3}"
print(re.findall(pattern, string))  # ['A123AA11', 'A222AA123', 'A123CC123']
```

To match only words that fully match the pattern, use word boundaries `\b`

```
pattern = r"\b[ABEKMHOPCTYX]\d{3}[ABEKMHOPCTYX]{2}\d{2,3}\b"
print(re.findall(pattern, string))  # ['A123AA11', 'A222AA123']
```